# Linking TF library problems in ROS

Tags: linker, listener, ros

I'm having a linker issue while using the `tf` library. Below is my `callback`. Without the only line in the `callback` there is no linker error. Please, find below the linker error itself.

```
void callback (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{

       listener->waitForTransform("/world_base_link", (*input).header.frame_id,  (*input).header.stamp, ros::Duration(5.0));

}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

      ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");
      ros::NodeHandle n;
      ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/kinect2/depth/points", 1, callback);
      ros::spin ();

}
```

Linker error:

```
Linking CXX executable range_image_border_extraction
CMakeFiles/range_image_border_extraction.dir/range_image_border_extraction.cpp.o: In function `callback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
range_image_border_extraction.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `tf::Transformer::waitForTransform(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time const&, ros::Duration const&, ros::Duration const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [range_image_border_extraction] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/range_image_border_extraction.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(range_image_border_extraction)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(range_image_border_extraction range_image_border_extraction.cpp)
target_link_libraries(range_image_border_extraction ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(range_image_border_extraction ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

package.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>

  <name>ipa325_com_client</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>Simulation client side communication interface</description>
  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>control_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>ipa325_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>ipa325_com_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>  
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>control_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>ipa325_com_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>ipa325_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>


  <export></export>

</package>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this linker error?

Comment: can you try adding `tf` into find_package: `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg tf)`